# Token transfer process

Tags: transactions, tokens, erc-20

I'm working on extracting all token holders and I've faced up with following issue: my assumption was that since token holders a stored in the state of token smart contract, the only way to obtain or transfer them it's to call a function of smart contract, i.e. send a transaction to the smart contract. But I've found such transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x61a0b16eeef9de8eac1b7279d11de20b987445f67707aed27bbd3e6aa3d76114

There is a transfer of the Tron tokens but 'To' field of the transaction is not a Tron smart contract address. How can it be possible?

May the second smart contract call function of the Tron smart contract?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May the second smart contract call function of the Tron smart contract?

Correct. You can see from [the Parity trace](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x61a0b16eeef9de8eac1b7279d11de20b987445f67707aed27bbd3e6aa3d76114&type=parity) calls to [contract `0xf230b790e05390fc8295f4d3f60332c93bed42e2`](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf230b790e05390fc8295f4d3f60332c93bed42e2), which is the contract for the Tron token.

Probably a better way to find all the token holders is to look for the `Transfer` events emitted by the token contract.